# Elastic dynamic mapping - restrict to objects only

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to create a dynamic mapping that allows object properties only in a document - as in, the doc only has object properties?

I didn't see anything about enforcing this in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

Example object:

```
{
  "object1": {
     "stuff": true,
  },
  "object2": {
     "other-stuff": 12,
     "more-stuff": "Some string"
  }
}
```

(Such that each top property must be an object)

Comment: Provide a concrete example please

Comment: Edited the post